# MVC View With "Content" in Name Not Loading, Showing VirtualFile instead

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view named _RequirementAreaExtranetContent.  When trying to load it, I get the VirtualFile content from my VirtualPathProvider.  I have boiled it down to the simplest HTML inside, and also replaced the content with that of a partial view that IS working.  Does anyone have any idea why it may not be loading?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you CANNOT have a view named *content*.  I cannot find this documented anywhere, but when I renamed it to _RequirementAreaExtranetContelt it worked fine.  I would love to know if anyone knows what happens with this, but hopefully it at least will save someone the headache I have from slamming their head against it for an hour :)